# Select the back most object on a powerpoint slide with via

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a task where I need to import a lot of emf graphics, convert them to shapes, ungroup, and delete the back most object. This object is not needed in what we are doing. I can select it with vba if I know what its name is, which I don't think is the same each time.

Does anyone have any suggesting as to how I select the back most object to delete it?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to select the graphic and 'edit picture' in the same way I can do it manually. I tried naming the graphic and selecting it with the name, then ungrouping it, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oBGShape As Shape
Dim lZorder As Long
Dim oTempRange As ShapeRange
Dim x As Long

Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("EMFGraphic")
lZorder = oSh.ZOrderPosition

' oSh.Ungroup returns a shaperange
With oSh.Ungroup
    ' ungrouping again is usually necessary
    ' we want the first shape in the new shaperange
    Set oTempRange = .Ungroup
    Set oBGShape = oTempRange(1)
End With

oBGShape.Fill.Visible = True
oBGShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(123, 123, 123)
oBGShape.Left = 0

MsgBox "The bg shape should now be at the left side of the slide and gray"

oBGShape.Delete


    While .ZOrderPosition > lZorder
        .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
    Wend

' If you want to regroup the shapes, you'll have to add them to an array
' after the first ungroup
' then use something like this to send the regrouped shape to the original
' zorder, if need be:
'        While .ZOrderPosition > lZorder
'        .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
'    Wend
```

Note that each time you run this, the original group's name will be lost and won't return with an un-do, so you'll have to re-apply the name to the graphic each time, if the name is what you're depending on to work with it.